# How to fix 'Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False' in A little GUI

Tags: python, numpy, view, anaconda, spyder

I was running A little GUI that allows to load and look at OCT volumes stored
as 3D Numpy arrays, it returned an error 'Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False'
This is the code already used by  developers in GitHub

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import os. path as op
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from glob import glob
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib. widgets import Button, Slider
datapath='E:/New folder\GlaucomaOCT'
class OCTViewer(object):
def __init__(self, datapath):
         self.cubepaths = self.read_cubepaths(datapath)
    self.cubeidx = 0
    self.cube_original = None
    self.cube = None
    self.name = None
    self.x = None
    self.y = None
    self.z = None
    self.threshold = 255
    self.init_gui()
def init_gui(self):
        mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
    bkg_color = (0.9, 0.9, 0.9)
    self.fig = plt.figure('OCT Viewer', figsize=(7, 7),facecolor=bkg_color)
    # scans and cube plots
    self.plt1 = self.fig.add_subplot(221)
    self.plt2 = self.fig.add_subplot(222)
    self.plt3 = self.fig.add_subplot(223)
    self.plt4 = self.fig.add_subplot(224, projection='3d')
    # Buttons
    self.fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)  # space for buttons
    axprev = self.fig.add_axes([0.4, 0.05, 0.1, 0.07])
    axnext = self.fig.add_axes([0.5, 0.05, 0.1, 0.07])
    self.bnext = Button(axnext, '>>', color='white')
    self.bnext.on_clicked(self.next_cube)
    self.bprev = Button(axprev, '<<', color='white')
    self.bprev.on_clicked(self.prev_cube)
    # Slider
    axthresh = self.fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.15, 0.8, 0.02])
    self.sthresh = Slider(axthresh, 'Thres', 0, 255, 255, '%3.0f',
                          color='lightgray')
    self.sthresh.on_changed(self.update_threshold)
    self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_hover)
    self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.on_key)

def read_cubepaths(self, datapath):
    inpath = op.join(datapath, '*.npy')
    return [fn for fn in glob(inpath)]
def load_cube(self):
    assert self. cubepaths, "No cubes found! Correct data path?"
    path = self.cubepaths[self.cubeidx]
    self.name = op.basename(path).replace('.npy', '')
    self.fig.suptitle(self.name)
    self.cube_original = np.load(path)
    self.update_threshold(self.threshold, False)
def init_cursor(self):
    if self.x is None:
        self.z, self.x, self.y = [s // 2 for s in self.cube.shape[:3]]
def show_cube(self, threshold=120):
    self.plt4.clear()
    self.plt4.set_axis_off()
    return  # disabled for speed
    # self.plt4.set_xticks([])
    # self.plt4.set_yticks([])
    # self.plt4.set_zticks([])
    # cube = self.cube.max(axis=3)  # max of RGB
    cube = self.cube[:, :, :, 2]  # only blue channel
    xs, ys, zs = np.where(cube > threshold)
    colors = self.cube[cube > threshold] / 255.0
    self.plt4.scatter(zs, ys, xs, c=colors,
                      marker='.', alpha=0.3, linewidth=0.0)
def show_scans(self):
    self.init_cursor()
    self.plt1.clear()
    self.plt2.clear()
    self.plt3.clear()
    self.plt1.axis('off')
    self.plt2.axis('off')
    self.plt3.axis('off')
    linecolor = (1, 1, 0, 0.2)
    self.plt1.imshow(self.cube[self.z, :, :], aspect='auto')
    self.plt1.axvline(x=self.x, color=linecolor)
    self.plt1.axhline(y=self.y, color=linecolor)
    self.plt2.imshow(self.cube[:, self.x, :], aspect='auto')
    self.plt2.axvline(x=self.x, color=linecolor)
    self.plt2.axhline(y=self.z, color=linecolor)
    self.plt3.imshow(self.cube[:, :, self.y], aspect='auto')
    self.plt3.axvline(x=self.y, color=linecolor)
    self.plt3.axhline(y=self.z, color=linecolor)
    self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
def save_scan(self):
    filename = 'bscan-' + self.name + ".jpg"
    plt.imsave(filename, self.cube[:, :, self.y], dpi=600)
def next_cube(self, event=None):
    self.cubeidx = min(self.cubeidx + 1, len(self.cubepaths) - 1)
    self.load_cube()
    self.show_cube()
    self.show_scans()
def prev_cube(self, event=None):
    self.cubeidx = max(self.cubeidx - 1, 0)
    self.load_cube()
    self.show_cube()
    self.show_scans()
def on_key(self, event):
    if event.key == 'right':
        self.next_cube()
    if event.key == 'left':
        self.prev_cube()
    if event.key == 's':
        self.save_scan()
def on_hover(self, event):
    if event.button != 1:  # left mouse button
        return
    if event.inaxes == self.plt1.axes:
        self.x, self.y = int(event.xdata), int(event.ydata)
        self.show_scans()
    if event.inaxes == self.plt2.axes:
        self.x, self.z = int(event.xdata), int(event.ydata)
        self.show_scans()
    if event.inaxes == self.plt3.axes:
        self.y, self.z = int(event.xdata), int(event.ydata)
        self.show_scans()
def update_threshold(self, val, redraw=True):
    self.threshold = int(val)
    self.cube = self.cube_original.copy()
    if self.threshold < 255:
        self.cube[:, :, :, 0] = 0
        threshold = self.threshold / 255.0 * np.max(self.cube)
        self.cube[self.cube > threshold] = 255
    if redraw:
        self.show_scans()
def run(self):
    self.load_cube()
    self.show_cube()
    self.show_scans()
    plt.show()
if __name__ == '__main__':
datapath = '.' if len(sys.argv) < 2 else sys.argv[1]
viewer = OCTViewer(datapath)
viewer.run()
```

But it gave me
ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False

Comment: `np.save/load` can save arrays that contain `objects`,not numeric (or string) elements.  To do that it uses `pickle`.  The docs explain that for security reasons, the user has to explicitly allow that.  According to the docs this was changed in version 1.16, so it's possible your developer created this code before that.

Comment: Please consider to format your code correctly, in that way it will be clearer for everyone

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line in the `load_cube` function:

```
self.cube_original = np.load(path)
```

to this:

```
self.cube_original = np.load(path, allow_pickle=True)
```